# Syntax error, also would like to know if i can make this code more efficient

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double weight, sgrav, distance, speed, pweight, distanceplanet, travel;
char selection;
string planet;
cout << "Welcome to INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL PROGRAM!" << endl;
cout << "This program enables you to find out your travel time to the planet" << endl;
cout << "you want to travel to as well as your weight on that planet." << endl;
cout << "Please enjoy the program and find the perfect planet for you!" << endl;
cout << endl
    << endl
    << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL MENU" << endl
    << "--------------------------" << endl
    << "a) Mercury" << endl
    << "b) Venus" << endl
    << "c) Earth" << endl
    << "d) Mars" << endl
    << "e) Jupiter" << endl
    << "f) Saturn" << endl
    << "g) Uranus" << endl
    << "h) Neptune" << endl
    << "q) quit" << endl
    <<endl

    << "Select a planet to travel to or q to quit the program: " << endl;
cin >> selection;
cout << "Please enter your weight (in lbs): " << endl;
cin >> weight;
cout << "Please enter the speed (in mile per hour) that you would like to travel at: " << endl
    << endl;
cin >> speed;

if (selection >= 'a' && selection <= 'h')
{
    if (selection == 'a')
    {
        sgrav = 0.86;
        pweight = (weight*sgrav);
        planet = "Mercury";
        distance = abs(36 - 93);
        travel = (distance * speed);
        cout << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL:  " << "Earth to " << planet << endl
            << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl
            << "Your weight on " << planet << ":      " << setprecision(2) << pweight << " lbs" << endl
            << endl
            << "Your travel time to " << planet << ":" << endl
            << "    In Hours: " << travel << " hours" << endl
            << "    In Days : " << (travel / 24) << " days" << endl
            << "    In years : " << (travel / 8760) << " years" << endl;

    }
    else if (selection == 'b')
    {
        sgrav = 0.86;
        pweight = (weight*sgrav);
        planet = "Venus";
        distance = abs(67 - 93);
        travel = (distance * speed);
        cout << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL:  " << "Earth to " << planet << endl
            << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl
            << "Your weight on " << planet << ":      " << setprecision(2) << pweight << " lbs" << endl
            << endl
            << "Your travel time to " << planet << ":" << endl
            << "    In Hours: " << travel << " hours" << endl
            << "    In Days : " << (travel / 24) << " days" << endl
            << "    In years : " << (travel / 8760) << " years" << endl;
    }
    else if (selection == 'c')
    {
        sgrav = 1.00;
        pweight = (weight*sgrav);
        planet = "Earth";
        distance = abs(93 - 93);
        travel = (distance * speed);
        cout << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL:  " << "Earth to " << planet << endl
            << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl
            << "Your weight on " << planet << ":      " << setprecision(2) << pweight << " lbs" << endl
            << endl
            << "Your travel time to " << planet << ":" << endl
            << "    In Hours: " << travel << " hours" << endl
            << "    In Days : " << (travel / 24) << " days" << endl
            << "    In years : " << (travel / 8760) << " years" << endl;
    }
    else if (selection == 'd')
    {
        sgrav = 0.37;
        pweight = (weight*sgrav);
        planet = "Mars";
        distance = abs(141 - 93);
        travel = (distance * speed);
        cout << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL:  " << "Earth to " << planet << endl
            << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl
            << "Your weight on " << planet << ":      " << setprecision(2) << pweight << " lbs" << endl
            << endl
            << "Your travel time to " << planet << ":" << endl
            << "    In Hours: " << travel << " hours" << endl
            << "    In Days : " << (travel / 24) << " days" << endl
            << "    In years : " << (travel / 8760) << " years" << endl;
    }
    else if (selection == 'e')
    {
        sgrav = 2.64;
        pweight = (weight*sgrav);
        planet = "Jupiter";
        distance = abs(483 - 93);
        travel = (distance * speed);
        cout << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL:  " << "Earth to " << planet << endl
            << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl
            << "Your weight on " << planet << ":      " << setprecision(2) << pweight << " lbs" << endl
            << endl
            << "Your travel time to " << planet << ":" << endl
            << "    In Hours: " << travel << " hours" << endl
            << "    In Days : " << (travel / 24) << " days" << endl
            << "    In years : " << (travel / 8760) << " years" << endl;
    }
    else if (selection == 'f')
    {
        sgrav = 1.17;
        pweight = (weight*sgrav);
        planet = "Saturn";
        distance = abs(886 - 93);
        travel = (distance * speed);
        cout << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL:  " << "Earth to " << planet << endl
            << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl
            << "Your weight on " << planet << ":      " << setprecision(2) << pweight << " lbs" << endl
            << endl
            << "Your travel time to " << planet << ":" << endl
            << "    In Hours: " << travel << " hours" << endl
            << "    In Days : " << (travel / 24) << " days" << endl
            << "    In years : " << (travel / 8760) << " years" << endl;
    }
    else if (selection == 'g')
    {
        sgrav = 0.92;
        pweight = (weight*sgrav);
        planet = "Uranus";
        distance = abs(1782 - 93);
        travel = (distance * speed);
        cout << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL:  " << "Earth to " << planet << endl
            << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl
            << "Your weight on " << planet << ":      " << setprecision(2) << pweight << " lbs" << endl
            << endl
            << "Your travel time to " << planet << ":" << endl
            << "    In Hours: " << travel << " hours" << endl
            << "    In Days : " << (travel / 24) << " days" << endl
            << "    In years : " << (travel / 8760) << " years" << endl;
    }
    else if (selection == 'h')
    {
        sgrav = 1.44;
        pweight = (weight*sgrav);
        planet = "Neptune";
        distance = abs(2793 - 93);
        travel = (distance * speed);
        cout << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL:  " << "Earth to " << planet << endl
            << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl
            << "Your weight on " << planet << ":      " << setprecision(2) << pweight << " lbs" << endl
            << endl
            << "Your travel time to " << planet << ":" << endl
            << "    In Hours: " << travel << " hours" << endl
            << "    In Days : " << (travel / 24) << " days" << endl
            << "    In years : " << (travel / 8760) << " years" << endl;
    }
}
else if (selection == 'q')
{
    cout << "You have chosen to quit the program. Thank you for using the program!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "You have entered an invalid selection." << endl;
}

//system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

Its awfully long for such a simple program, and i was wondering if anyone would know a more efficient way to output the information using if-else statements instead of copy pasting into each case. Also, I am getting a syntax error on the line where i declare my double variables, and its with the semi colon, and i don't understand why.

Comment: Show us the error you get

Comment: error C2059: syntax error : ';' at the double declaration

Comment: When you repeat the same code again and again it's time to refactor: extract the printing part to another method and call this method with the relevant arguments: sgrav,  planet etc.

Comment: Why can't you use switch ?    `<<endl` here you don't have `;` also.

Comment: I was advised to use the if-else, and how would I call the function in an efficient manner? Sorry if its a dumb question, i just dont understand how I would make the code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `if (selection >= 'a' && selection <= 'h')` The user could have caps lock pressed, so consider A~Z also

2) (in my opinion) Quit should be at the start of logic.

3) You can use switch(selection) instead. dafault: Invalid Input. Try again.

4) Put your output in a function and pass the variables to it, instead of writting the same code over again

```
void prn(float sgrav, int pweight, char arr[], float distance, float travel)
{
cout << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL:  " << "Earth to " << planet << endl
     << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl
     << "Your weight on " << planet << ":      " << setprecision(2) << pweight << " lbs" << endl
     << endl
     << "Your travel time to " << planet << ":" << endl
     << "    In Hours: " << travel << " hours" << endl
     << "    In Days : " << (travel / 24) << " days" << endl
     << "    In years : " << (travel / 8760) << " years" << endl;
}
```